# Centering text in passwordBox in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

I'm trying to center the text in a PassWord box:

In Blend the Text properties for alignment are all disabled.
Is there another way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HorizontalContentAlignment works in WPF, doesn't seem to work in Silverlight though unfortunately.

```
<PasswordBox Height="23" Width="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

For Silverlight you need to tweak the template for the PasswordBox a little - you can extract the template for the password box (in Blend right click the PasswordBox, select 'Edit Template -> Edit a Copy') and then set the HorizontalAlignment on the ContentElement to {TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment} - e.g.

```
<Border x:Name="ContentElement" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
```

Then it seems to have the same behaviour as the WPF version and you can set HorizontalContentAlignment on the PasswordBox element as required.

Comment: I am using UWP where I tried Password Box but Its not working here