# How to make the Content in a Password Box in Xaml to be center?

Tags: xaml, passwordbox

I am trying to make the content, in a Password box to align in center , when we type something in that, but I am not able to do it.I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366248/centering-text-in-passwordbox-in-xaml?answertab=votes#tab-top)

this is the code:

```
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="4" Password="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="550" Height="90" PlaceholderText="password" >
    <PasswordBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush  ImageSource="/Assets/Login/text-field.png"   AlignmentY="Bottom"></ImageBrush>
    </PasswordBox.Background>
</PasswordBox>
```

**This is for a windows store app**.
But not sure how they are doing.I would be grateful if anyone could answer this.

Comment: Is this for silverlight or wpf or winrt or what? Once we know that it will be an easy fix, generally though it's either just `HorizontalContentAlignment` or `TextAlignment` = center

Comment: It is not working..I used it..

Comment: Ok no problem, worse that could happen is we just go edit the style template, so which tech are you working with so we can go take a look at the default style template? SL, WPF, RT, etc?

Comment: I have used styles for password ..but I am not sure what changes should I make..I am using WRT..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie with the [PasswordBox Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468216%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The root Border element doesn't have TemplateBindings.

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            CornerRadius="2"
            Padding="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
      </Border.Background>
      <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
      </Border.BorderBrush>
      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
          <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
          <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
          <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
    </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

try adding an encapsulating Grid or modifying the Border's HorizontalAlignment it to something like this:

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            CornerRadius="2"
            Padding="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
      </Border.Background>
      <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
      </Border.BorderBrush>
      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
          <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
          <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
          <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
    </Border>
   </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

Then load your style as a StaticResource

Comment: @KiranKumar are you sure you are using winrt(windows store apps) ? as  your question xaml is look like winrt xaml ...and **PlaceholderText** is  not available in wpf..and Musters answer is for wpf..Musters answer will not work in winrt as winrt do not supports  DynamicResource and this style.

Comment: I am not sure what you are point is, but what I have done is, I used PasswordBox style and in that I used the <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"> ..</Grid> and "HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"..and it got resolved..